# Consider the following BNF grammar (BNF, Recursion)

Tags: recursion, bnf

Write a BNF grammar for recognizing all sentences in the form of anbn-2, where n>1.
 For example, aa, aaab, aaaabb are all accepted,
 but abbb, aab, aabb are not 
(Hint: use recursion).

This is my derivation:
S ::= AZ 
Z ::= A | AAB 
A ::= a 
B ::= b 
Is this correct?

**EDIT**: Maybe this is correct?

S -> a | X | Y      
                                                                                           X-> aX | a      
                                                                                                   Y -> aX | b

Answer (score 0):

Both are completely incorrect.

First grammar: since A turns only to a, and B only to b, we can replace A by a and B by b. The grammar will be:

```
S -> aZ
Z -> a
Z -> aab
```

Thus, S turns to either aa or aaab, but not, for example, aaaabb.

Second grammar: use the first rule and turn S to a.  Since a is not a valid word, the grammar is also incorrect.  (Alternatively, we could turn S to X, then X to aX 9 times, then X to a, making aaaaaaaaaa, which is also invalid).

Answer (score 0):

Your first grammar only produces:

```
S -> AZ -> aZ -> aa
S -> AZ -> aZ -> aAAB -> aaab
```

Your second grammar allows words containing only `a`'s, which are not part of the language. For instance:

```
S -> a
```

I'd simply start with two `a`'s and then produce arbitrary pairs. Hence, the grammar looks like ([BNF syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)):

```
<term> ::= "aa" | "aa" <pair>
<pair> ::= "ab" | "a" <pair> "b"
```

Example:

```
<term> -> "aa"
<term> -> "aa" <pair> -> "aaab"
<term> -> "aa" <pair> -> "aaa" <pair> "b" -> "aaaabb"
...
```